# Send function(with parameters) inside the JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, function

I am trying to pass function(with parameter) to another function inside the json object. It always undefined and I couldn't find the reason.

First triggering `packtNs.graduateForm.loadEvent` function. Then sending 
`packtNs.common.populateWithTodaysDate("packt_supervisor", "packt_postgraduatestartdate")` function to `packtNs.common.wireOnChangeEvents` function.

Here is my code:

```
var packtNs = packtNs || {};

packtNs.common = packtNs.common || {};

/**
* A method that populates the post graduate start date
* when the supervisor lookup is populated.
* @returns {Void}
*/

packtNs.common.populateWithTodaysDate = function(attributeToMonitor, dateAttributeToChange)
{
    console.log("Populatewithtodaysdate function triggered");
}

packtNs.common.wireOnChangeEvents =
    function(eventAttributeTuples){
        debugger;
        for (var i in eventAttributeTuples) {
           console.log(eventAttributeTuples[i].attribute);
           ////attribute is OK
           console.log(eventAttributeTuples[i].function);
           ////function is always undefined. eventAttributeTuples[0] object doesnt have function - tried different names
        }

}

packtNs.graduateForm = packtNs.graduateForm || {};

packtNs.graduateForm.loadEvent = function(){
    packtNs.common.wireOnChangeEvents([
        { 
            attribute: "packt_supervisor",
            function:packtNs.common.populateWithTodaysDate("packt_supervisor", "packt_postgraduatestartdate")
        }
    ]);
    debugger;
}
```

Comment: "inside the json object." - JSON is a string representation of data, it does not "contain" functions

Comment: `function` is a reserved word and should not be used as a property name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Comment: Tried different names. Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a name spaced object not JSON, but to get something you have to return something.  I renamed your "function" to "mything" because well it was wrong.

```js
var packtNs = packtNs || {};

packtNs.common = packtNs.common || {};

/**
 * A method that populates the post graduate start date
 * when the supervisor lookup is populated.
 * @returns {Void}
 */

packtNs.common.populateWithTodaysDate = function(attributeToMonitor, dateAttributeToChange) {
  console.log("Populatewithtodaysdate function triggered");
  return {
    arg1: attributeToMonitor,
    arg2: dateAttributeToChange
  };
}

packtNs.common
  .wireOnChangeEvents = function(eventAttributeTuples) {
    //debugger;
    console.log("tup:", eventAttributeTuples);
    for (var i in eventAttributeTuples) {
      console.log(eventAttributeTuples[i].attribute);
      ////attribute is OK
      console.log(eventAttributeTuples[i].mything);
      ////function is always undefined. eventAttributeTuples[0] object doesnt have function - tried different names
    }
    return eventAttributeTuples;
  }

packtNs.graduateForm = packtNs.graduateForm || {};

packtNs.graduateForm.loadEvent = function() {
  return packtNs.common.wireOnChangeEvents([{
    attribute: "packt_supervisor",
    mything: packtNs.common.populateWithTodaysDate("packt_supervisor", "packt_postgraduatestartdate")
  }]);
  // debugger;
}

var myresult = packtNs.graduateForm.loadEvent();
console.log("myresult:",myresult);
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, as pointed out in comments under your question, change attribute name from "function" to something different. Then I'll recommend you to try call passed string representation of function into eval method (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)